# How to save from Listview to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, listview, vb.net-2010

I am trying to save data from a listview control to Microsoft SQL Server. When I run the code no any error is showing but the data is not been saved in the database. Can someone kindly help me?

```
Private Sub Save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(InvoiceClass.GetConnectionString()) ' My Connection String
        con.Open()
        For Each item As ListViewItem In Lstview.Items
            Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SP_InvoiceSave", con)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", item.SubItems(0).Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", item.SubItems(1).Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SellingPrice", item.SubItems(2).Text)
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
        Next
        MsgBox("done")
    End Sub
```

Comment: you should call command.ExecuteNonQuery() instead of making an object of SqlDataAdapter.

Comment: Strange really - not executing your query doesn't execute it...
Anyway it's good practise to dispose of your objects once you're done - either call dispose, or wrap them in a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

            Dim con As New SqlConnection(InvoiceClass.GetConnectionString()) ' My Connection String
            'open connection
            con.Open()
            For Each item As ListViewItem In Lstview.Items
                Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SP_InvoiceSave", con)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", item.SubItems(0).Text)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", item.SubItems(1).Text)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SellingPrice", item.SubItems(2).Text)
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                command.ExecuteNonQuery() 
            Next
            MsgBox("done")
            'closing connection
            conn.Close()

End Sub
```